# Splunk - Create customized query for Splunk dashboard based on Input selection

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I'm creating a Dashboard in Splunk.
It has one dropdown menu to select App-name(App1 or App2), another drop-down to select log_type (Detailed and App_specific), and a Search panel to show output of search query.

For instance,

1. If user selects App1 and log_type as app_specific, then the Panel should result for the query:

`index=App1 "taskExecutor-1" | sort -_time | table msg`

For App1, selecting app_specific should add "taskExecutor-1" to the query.

2. If user selects App2 and log_type as app_specific, then the Panel should result for the query:

`index=App2 "ool-44-thread-1" | sort -_time | table msg`

For App2, selecting app_specific should add "ool-44-thread-1" to the query.

3. 1. If user selects App1 and log_type as Detailed, then the Panel should result for the query:

`index=App1 | sort -_time | table msg`

Selecting Detailed should not anything to the query. Or we can say, an empty value.

How can I customize the query to accommodate such behavior in Splunk? Is there any any if/else or case functionality in Splunk that can help achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Investigate [dashboard tokens](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/TokenReference)

In your input field(s) (radio, dropdown, etc) on your dashboard, set the token to have multiple possible options (static or dynamic - your choice)

Then in your SPL, do the following:

```
index=ndx "$mytoken$" msg=*
| sort 0 - _time
| table msg
```

Comment: I understand that part of using Splunk Tokens. But I want an if-else condition in the SPL, so I don't have to create multiple tokens.

Comment: @user2769790 - my example only uses one token - it just gets different values based on the selection made :)

Comment: Yeah. But then, I will have to create a separate token for "ool-44-thread-1" and "taskExecutor-1". I have already created tokens for App2 and App1 and log_type. if someone selects App1 and log_type as app_specific, then the query should be automatically able to use "taskExecutor-1" in the query.. if someone selects App1 and log_type as detailed, then the query should be automatically able to use " "/empty. For App2 and app_specific,  the query should be automatically able to use "ool-44-thread-1". Hope this helps understanding my goal.

Comment: @user2769790 - then use a dynamically-populated token: you cannot having to enumerate options...if you want the options *enumerated*